# For loop only running once in openFile function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to use a function to read an external file and split segments of it into an array using a for loop. For some reason the for loop only occurs once and I cant figure out why for the life of me.

I've tried commenting out sections of the code to see if anything in particular is causing it but I cant seem to isolate it exactly

```
function nthIndex(str, pat, n){ //just used to put string of hsl values from txt file into cArray 
    var L= str.length, i= -1;
    while(n-- && i++<L){
        i= str.indexOf(pat, i);
        if (i < 0) break;
    }
    return i;
}

function openFile(event){
var input = event.target;
var r = new FileReader();
r.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    r.onload = function(){
    var text = r.result;
    var n = 3;
    var index1 = 0;
    var index2 = nthIndex(text,",",n)
        for(c=0;c<361;c++){ //WHY DOESNT THIS LOOP
        var value = text.slice(index1, indexOf(",",index2));
        cArray.push(value);
        index1 = indexOf(",",index2);
        index2 = nthIndex(text,",",n+3);
        }
    window.alert(cArray[0];
        window.alert(cArray[360];)// just to test
    draw(cArray)} // this isnt relavent
};
```

The result should show an alert the first and last element in the `cArray` array but it doesnt show at all. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors, undefined variables & logic bugs.

Comment: The variable you are looping over `c` has not been declared. Like Programnik mentioned, you should probably check the console for errors to guide your debugging of this function.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, im kind of new to coding so I make a lot of dumb mistakes, i will check my console for errors